# Error when try to import URL Json to Excel

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping, winhttprequest

I'm trying to import the information in JSON format from the following Url by WinHttpRequest:
https://bet.hkjc.com/football/getJSON.aspx?jsontype=odds_allodds.aspx&matchid=default

```
Sub test()

Dim xmlhttp As Object
Dim strUrl As String: strUrl = "https://bet.hkjc.com/football/getJSON.aspx?jsontype=odds_allodds.aspx&matchid=default"
Dim objRequest As Object

Set objRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .send
    End With

    Debug.Print objRequest.responseText

End Sub
```

However, it just shows nothing similar to the Url but a lot of garbled messages.

I would like to know how to address this problem. 
The code works fine if I use other Url.

Comment: Show what it returns!  Could be proxy issues on your machine or any number of other things, but without showing that response, people will just be guessing.

Comment: @Marc the response contains some chinese and "?". therefore i ddnt put it in, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### XHR:

I believe the page has bot prevention measures in place whereby, if it suspects you are a bot a challenge is raised which requires javascript to run. If that runs successfully an XHR request is issued with info from the challenge in the headers and that, were you to be using a browser, would lead to your content being correctly updated to show expected values.

The first time I ran GET request I got the expected json response and after that I got the following:

```js
<HTML>
<head>
<script>
Challenge=649275;
ChallengeId=473313563;
GenericErrorMessageCookies="Cookies must be enabled in order to view this page.";
</script>
<script>
function test(var1)
{
    var var_str=""+Challenge;
    var var_arr=var_str.split("");
    var LastDig=var_arr.reverse()[0];
    var minDig=var_arr.sort()[0];
    var subvar1 = (2 * (var_arr[2]))+(var_arr[1]*1);
    var subvar2 = (2 * var_arr[2])+var_arr[1];
    var my_pow=Math.pow(((var_arr[0]*1)+2),var_arr[1]);
    var x=(var1*3+subvar1)*1;
    var y=Math.cos(Math.PI*subvar2);
    var answer=x*y;
    answer-=my_pow*1;
    answer+=(minDig*1)-(LastDig*1);
    answer=answer+subvar2;
    return answer;
}
</script>
<script>
client = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    var client=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        client = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    };
}
if (!((!!client)&&(!!Math.pow)&&(!!Math.cos)&&(!![].sort)&&(!![].reverse)))
{
    document.write("Not all needed JavaScript methods are supported.<BR>");

}
else
{
    client.onreadystatechange  = function()
    {
        if(client.readyState  == 4)
        {
            var MyCookie=client.getResponseHeader("X-AA-Cookie-Value");
            if ((MyCookie == null) || (MyCookie==""))
            {
                document.write(client.responseText);
                return;
            }
            
            var cookieName = MyCookie.split('=')[0];
            if (document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName)==-1)
            {
                document.write(GenericErrorMessageCookies);
                return;
            }
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    };
    y=test(Challenge);
    client.open("POST",window.location,true);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge-ID', ChallengeId);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge-Result',y);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge',Challenge);
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type' , 'text/plain');
    client.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Whether you mimic what the javascript is doing and pass as a new XHR I am unsure (haven' looked closely).

You could also try browser automation e.g. IE via Microsoft Internet Controls or Chrome/FF etc via Selenium Basic, to see if letting javascript run on the  page gets around this problem.

---

### Handling challenge: (WIP)

I started looking at an attempt to handle this. Currently, I keep getting the json response so haven't fully tested the bottom part. I would expect some **minute** <sub>*do we care?</sub> margin for error if only because `Math.PI` gives `3.141592653589793`, whereas `Application.PI` gives `3.14159265358979`

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim json As Object, s As String, re As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Dim pattern1 As String, pattern2 As String, challenge As Long, challengeId As Long
    Const URL As String = "https://bet.hkjc.com/football/getJSON.aspx?jsontype=odds_allodds.aspx&matchid=default"
    pattern1 = "Challenge=(\d+);"
    pattern2 = "ChallengeId=(\d+);"
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        s = .responseText
        On Error Resume Next
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not json Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "No challenge issued"
            Debug.Print .responseText
        Else
            On Error GoTo errhand
            challenge = GetId(re, s, pattern1)
            If challenge = 999 Then Exit Sub     'should really use more unlikely value.
            challengeId = GetId(re, s, pattern2)
            .Open "POST", URL, False
            .setRequestHeader "X-AA-Challenge-ID", challengeId
            .setRequestHeader "X-AA-Challenge-Result", CLng(GetAnswer(challenge))
            .setRequestHeader "X-AA-Challenge", challenge
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/plain"
            .send ""
            Debug.Print .Status, .responseText
            If .Status = 200 Then
                .Open "GET", URL, False
                .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
                .send
                s = .responseText
                Debug.Print s
            End If
        End If
    End With
    Exit Sub
errhand:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
End Sub

Public Function GetId(ByVal re As Object, ByVal s As String, ByVal pattern As String) As Long
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = pattern
        If .TEST(s) Then
            GetId = .Execute(s)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetId = 999                          '<probably should use a more unlikely number here!
        End If
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetAnswer(ByVal challenge As Long) As String 'var1  'challenge
    Dim var_str As String, var_arr() As Long, LastDig As Long, minDig As Long
    Dim i As Long

    var_str = Chr$(34) & challenge & Chr$(34)
    ReDim var_arr(0 To Len(var_str) - 3)

    For i = 2 To Len(var_str) - 1
        var_arr(i - 2) = CLng(Mid$(var_str, i, 1))
    Next i

    LastDig = var_arr(UBound(var_arr))
    minDig = Application.Min(var_arr)

    Dim my_pow As Long, x As Long, y As Long, answer As Variant
    Dim subvar1 As Long, subvar2 As String

    subvar1 = 2 * Application.Small(var_arr, 3) + Application.Small(var_arr, 2)
    subvar2 = CStr(2 * Application.Small(var_arr, 3)) & CStr(Application.Small(var_arr, 2))
    my_pow = (minDig + 2) ^ Application.Small(var_arr, 2)
    x = challenge * 3 + (subvar1 * 1)
    y = Evaluate("=COS(PI()* " & CLng(subvar2) & ")")
    answer = x * y
    answer = answer - my_pow
    answer = answer + minDig - LastDig
    answer = CStr(answer) & subvar2
    GetAnswer = answer
End Function
```

---

### Browser based solution:

Standard IE automation with Microsoft Internet Controls lead to SaveAs/Open Dialog prompt.

Using selenium you can avoid this prompt and grab the data from the pre element. Using selenium allows you to benefit from an implicit wait which allows the page to complete any challenge issued. You can increase the wait using explicit wait conditions.

```
Option Explicit
'download selenium https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0
'Ensure latest applicable driver e.g. ChromeDriver.exe in Selenium folder
'VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to selenium type library
Public Sub DownloadFile()
    Dim d As WebDriver, jsonText As String
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://bet.hkjc.com/football/getJSON.aspx?jsontype=odds_allodds.aspx&matchid=default"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        jsonText = .FindElementByCss("pre").Text
        Debug.Print jsonText
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### References:

Note I am using a [json parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). After adding the .bas from that link you need to go VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

---

1 Some perspective from the RubberDuckVBA crew [1](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/edu/news/2016/3/16/how-many-decimals-of-pi-do-we-really-need/) and [2](https://twitter.com/doom_txt/status/1106238987687976962/photo/1)